# What is the maximum speed of ADSL?

Tags: internet, performance, adsl

As wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_Digital_Subscriber_Line) the max speed of ADSL is 24.0 Mbit/s. However [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_in_Japan) it writes that Japan provides ADSL service with speed **50 Mbit/s**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ADSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU_G.992.5_Annex_M) max is 24 Mbit. Japan's DSL service providing 50Mbit is [VDSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_High_Speed_Digital_Subscriber_Line).

Answer (score 3):

VDSL (ITU G.993.2) has a profile that can do 200Mbps, that's the fastest ratified today I believe.